# Getting bar chart height in Core-Plot

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-plot, bar-chart

I am trying to make stack bar graph with use Core-Plot.

[image]

In last station,labels are not centered. I thought, if i can find height of each bar, i can place labels to the center of bars. How can i find height of bars? Or is there any easy way place the labels center of bars?

Thanks for your answer and advice.Sorry for my bad english :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use plot space annotations instead of data labels. They will move with the plots if you pan and zoom. The center of a bar is easy to calculate since the annotation is positioned in data coordinates. Many of the example apps add annotations to scatter plots in response to user action. The same annotation code will work with any plot type.

For example, the center of the first green bar is at (5, 3.5).

```
NSArray *anchorPoint = @[@5, @3.5];

CPTTextLayer *textLayer = [[CPTTextLayer alloc] initWithText:@"Label Text"
                                                       style:[CPTTextStyle textStyle]];

textAnnotation = [[CPTPlotSpaceAnnotation alloc] initWithPlotSpace:graph.defaultPlotSpace
                                                   anchorPlotPoint:anchorPoint];
textAnnotation.contentLayer = textLayer;
[plot addAnnotation:textAnnotation];
```

Comment: Hey Eric, thanks for replay, which delegate should i use for this? Can you give me code example?